# Magento 2 Page Builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks

Tags: magento2, page-builder

Unable to CMS pages and block if having content from page builder after upgraded from 2.3.1 to 2.3.5 p2 version

spinner showing continuously and getting error in console as "Page Builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks"

Could you please advise any one

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should see this issue if you've upgraded to magento 2.3.5-p2. This issue comes up when you have more than one page builder elements on the same page. Mostly causes issue when you have a custom page builder element on page for your custom attribute.

To fix this issue, in your uiComponent add the following item nodes under wysiwyg config.

```
<item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
<item name="pagebuilder_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

You can find full example on github issue page
https://github.com/mirasvit/module-blog/issues/162

**Note:** This has been fixed in Magento 2.3.6
https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/release-notes.html#133-for-magento-commerce-236

Comment: Enabled button of Page Builder fixes my issue in Magento 2.4.0