# Page Builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks

Tags: magento2, attributes, uicomponent, page-builder

My products have small descriptions and description attributes.
A small description is a Tinymce field and a description is a pagebuilder.

When I edit a product, if I open the content section, here these 2 fields are visible, and when I try to save it I get the error "Page Builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks." on my console.

I did a search, and I found this [Magento 2 Page Builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326364/magento-2-page-builder-was-rendering-for-5-seconds-without-releasing-locks)
I try it on vendor files and it solves my issue. So undo all the changes and extend the ui_component. But now my changes don't work and the error is always there.

The file that I want to change is:
vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pagebuilder_text_form.xml

I create a new file to extend this at:
app/design/adminhtml/MY_FOLDER/MY_THEME/Magento_PageBuilder/ui_component/pagebuilder_text_form.xml

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Do you have any suggestions to solve my issue?

Thank you in advance